# eloquent Laravel nested where or for 2 between

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello i try query something in this way :

```
$result = DB:table('tableA')
          ->join('tableB','tableB.id','=','TableA.tid')
->join('tableC','tableB.sd','=','TableC.id')
 ->where('tableC.number', '=', '1')
 ->where('tableB.lang', '=', 'en')
->where(function ($q,$regFilterVal) {
                    // Nested OR condition
                    $q->whereBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal)
                        ->orBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal);
                })
```

i try too changing the last part :

```
->where(function ($q,$regFilterVal) {
                    // Nested OR condition
                    $q->whereBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal)
                        ->orBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal);
                })
by:
 ->whereBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal)
                        ->orBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal)
```

But not working , this that i try to do is working in sql :

```
and (TableC.numberMin between (a1,a2) or TableC.numberMax between (a1,a2))
```

then in resumen i want add a where condition ....
and (condition1 or condition2) where the 2 conditions are betweens, how is the correct sintax in eloquent for do this

Comment: I forget say that var $regFilterVal is a array that contains the min and max values , passed to the condition whereBetween who get how param the array

Comment: In your posted code you are not using `numberMax`, Both between clauses applied on `numberMin`

Comment: is a example... i found yet the reply yet .. only i not put the variable in good order  ->where(function($query) use ($regFilterVal) {
                    // Nested OR condition
                    $query->whereBetween('b',  $regFilterVal)
                        ->orwhereBetween('c',  $regFilterVal);
                })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with the callback

Try this -

```
$result = DB:table('tableA')
          ->join('tableB','tableB.id','=','TableA.tid')
->join('tableC','tableB.sd','=','TableC.id')
 ->where('tableC.number', '=', '1')
 ->where('tableB.lang', '=', 'en')
->where(function ($q) use($regFilterVal) {
                    // Nested OR condition
                    $q->whereBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal)
                        ->orBetween('tableC.numberMin',  $regFilterVal);
                })
```

Comment: just; i comment on up, i not see that we need out the param in the exterior with use , thank you